# Setting Thread Inheritance options in Pthreads for PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

Is there any way to specify what a thread should inherit when using a Pool, the same way you can in Thread:

```
$thread = new MyThread();
$thread->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_INI | PTHREADS_INHERIT_CONSTANTS);
```

I'm looking for a way to do it with a Pool, something like:

```
$pool->shutdown(<options>);// doesn't work
```

I couldn't find any way to do it in the docs. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pool` takes a `Worker` class in `__construct`:

```
new Pool(8, MyWorker::class);
```

Where `MyWorker` looks something like:

```
class MyWorker {
    public function start() {
        return parent::start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_INI | PTHREADS_INHERIT_CONSTANTS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! By the way, I had to change `public function start()` to `public function start($options = null)` otherwise it gave me an error `Declaration of PoolWorker::start() should be compatible with Thread::start($options = NULL)`